# How do I access the REST API's in Wordpress 4.1.1

Tags: wordpress, rest

I am using wordpress and according to the documentation [here](http://wp-api.org/) I download it, install it and activate it. However, it doesn't seem to be working when I go to

```
localhost/wp-json/posts
```

I get a 404

I think there may be a couple issues, one the official plugin site does not say it supports 4.1, however, some info suggests it may be included by default. Also I tried using the git repo and that didn't seem to work either.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I changed permalinks to post name and I uncommented mod_rewrite in my httpd.conf but no dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You need to be using pretty permalinks to use the plugin, as it uses custom rewrite rules to power the API.

Check your permalink settings and be sure to your web server support rewrite.

Comment: What does pretty mean? Is that Post name?

Comment: Tried adding mod_rewrite and use "post name" as my permalink sign but nothing

Comment: Missed this "If your .htaccess file were writable, we could do this automatically, but it isn’t so these are the mod_rewrite rules you should have in your .htaccess file. Click in the field and press CTRL + a to select all."

Comment: Pretty permalink mean url structure that use rewrite. Change WordPress' default `?p=123`. Yes post name is a pretty permalinks.

Comment: There's a ticket to set pretty permalinks as default starting with 4.2, so pretty soon you won't need to worry about this.